# why TextBox is automatically Empty on ajax call

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am Filling text box by using Web method But after few second textbox clear automatically i dont understand why?

**Code behind**

```
[WebMethod]
public static ServiceReference1.CUSTOMER[] GetCutomerCode(string DivisionCode, string CountryCode, string LocationCode)
{
   ServiceReference1.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new ServiceReference1.MasterDataServiceClient();
   ServiceReference1.CUSTOMER[] CustCode = oClient.GetCustomers(DivisionCode, CountryCode, LocationCode, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "1");
   return CustCode;
 }
```

**AJAX**

```
var AllCustCode = [];
function YourJavaScriptFunction() {
    var params = { DivisionCode: '1000', CountryCode: 'SAU', LocationCode: '325', };
    var cc = $("input[id$='txtText1']").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        url: 'Header.aspx/GetCutomerCode',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (res) {
            CustomerCode(res.d)
            OnSuccessCostCall();
        }
    });
    function CustomerCode(pdata) {
        AllCustCode = pdata;
    }

    function OnSuccessCostCall(data, status) {
        result = AllCustCode;

        if (result != undefined && result.length > 0) {
            $.each(result, function (idx2, val2) {
                var str = val2.CustomerCode;
                var Price = val2.CustomerPriceGroupCode;
                var ChannelCode = val2.ChannelCode;
                var SubChannelCode = val2.SubChannelCode;
                if (cc == str) {

                    $("input[id$='txtText2']").val(Price);
                    $("input[id$='txtText3']").val(ChannelCode);
                    $("input[id$='txtText4']").val(SubChannelCode);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am binding all text box on `ButtonClick` event and everything is working as expected but after few second all text box clear automatically where i am doing mistake Please suggest me any solution for that

**Button Click**

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClientClick="return YourJavaScriptFunction(); return false;" />
```

Where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: YourJavaScriptFunction function should return false. and remove OnClientClick="return YourJavaScriptFunction(); return false;" from here

Comment: Wao!! Working like champ